# Deal with apostrophe in java regex in replaceALL

Tags: java, regex

Trying the replace only the EXACT & WHOLE OCCURRENCES of pattern using the following code. Apparently you in you'll is being replaced as @@@'ll. But what I want is only `you` to be replaced.

Please suggest.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Fielreadingtest{


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String MyText  = "I knew about you long before I met you. I also know that you’re an awesome person. By the way you’ll be missed. ";
     String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    System.out.println("Before:" + newLine + MyText);
    String pattern = "\\byou\\b";
    MyText = MyText.replaceAll(pattern, "@@@");
    System.out.println("After:" + newLine +MyText);

}
}

/*
Before:
I knew about you long before I met you. I also know that you’re an awesome person. By the way you’ll be missed. 
After:
I knew about @@@ long before I met @@@. I also know that @@@’re an awesome person. By the way @@@’ll be missed. 

*/
```

This being said I have an input file which contains a list of words that I want to skip which looks like this:
[image]

Now as per @Anubhav I have to use `(^|\\s)you([\\s.]|$)` to replace exactly `you` but not anything else. Is my best bet to use a tool like notepad++ and pre & post fix all my input words as above or change something in the code itslef. The code I'm using is this:

```
  for (String pattern : patternsToSkip) {
     line = line.replaceAll(pattern, "");
   }
```

source: https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount2_source.html?scroll=topic_7_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use this regex:

```
String pattern = "(^|\\s)you([\\s.,;:-]|$)";
```

This will match `"you"` only at:

- start or preceded by a space
- end or followed by a space OR a some listed punctuation characters

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. Since I cannot add images here I'm extending my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
\b(you)(?!['’])
```

Escaped for a Java string:

```
"\\b(you)(?!['’])"
```

Your demo input contains a different apostrophe than on my keyboard. I've put both in the negative lookahead.

```
 import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
 import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

 /**
    <P>{@code java ReplaceYouWholeWordWithAtAtAt}</P>
  **/
 public class ReplaceYouWholeWordWithAtAtAt  {
    public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

       String sRegex = "\\byou(?!['’])";

       String sToSearch = "I knew about you long before I met you. I also know that you’re an awesome person. By the way you’ll be missed.";
       String sRplcWith = "@@@";

       Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sRegex).matcher(sToSearch);
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       while(m.find())  {
          m.appendReplacement(sb, sRplcWith);
       }
       m.appendTail(sb);

       System.out.println(sb);
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ReplaceYouWholeWordWithAtAtAt
 I knew about @@@ long before I met @@@. I also know that youÆre an awesome person. By the way youÆll be missed.
```

Comment: You are using a different apostrophe than I expected. I updated my answer.